# Android + Sum up values of a parse query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have the following problem:
I want to sum up the ratings (coloumn “Rating”) and later calculate an average rating. 
Unfortunately this doesn’t work, and it seems to me that the problem lies with or within the foreach loop. The variable avg has no value after the loop and i don't see the reason for this.
Thank you very much for your help.

Table "RateAndComment"
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3831/y23ygngp_png.htm

```
    protected double totalRating;
    protected int i;
    protected float avg;

public void CalculateRating(String objectId)
    {


        //ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("RateAndComment");
        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("RateAndComment");
        query.whereEqualTo("PlaceObjectId",objectId);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void done(List<ParseObject>list,
                                    com.parse.ParseException e) {
                                       if (e == null) {
                                           i=0;
                                           for (ParseObject obj : list) {
                                               totalRating = totalRating + obj.getDouble("Rating");
                                               i = i + 1;
                                           }
                                       } else {
                                           Log.d("Post retrieval", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                                       }
                                   }

                               }
        );
        avg = (float) totalRating/i;
        avgRating(objectId);
    }
```

Comment: are you familiar with the term `asynchronous`?

Comment: With the word yes, but to be honest, i don't see how it fit's for this problem. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: have you started by reading the doc? https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#findInBackground%28%29

Comment: (the keywords here are `in background`)

Comment: I read the document: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries

Comment: I understand now what you want to tell me with the term asynchronous and I see the problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FindCallback`'s `done` method you pass into `query.findInBackground` is executed at a later point in time (after the query has completed).

```
avg = (float) totalRating/i;
avgRating(objectId);
```

Is being executed before `i` is calculated. Move it inside of the `done` method and you should be good.
There will be a delay after calling `CalculateRating` before `avgRating` is called, so you should probably show some loading UI or some other indication that something is happening in the background.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and explanation. Now it works fine, performance is not an issue yet, but i will keep it in mind.

Comment: As findInBackground performs a network request, your end users will likely experience performance issues when they use your app on a 3G (or worse) connection. Always good to keep in mind.